# Trying to understand where to start with Rasbperry PI, Java and Jazelle

Tags: java

My project in class is requiring me to get an audio player to work with Rasbperry, Java and Arm Jazelle technology. I've been reading here and there trying to understand what Jazelle is and how to use it to run Java on the Rasbperry but everything is still a bit unclear. I just need simple explanation of what to do just as a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jazelle is an old, secret acceleration technology for Java Virtual Machines included in some ARM processors (e.g. the ones used by the Raspberry Pi 1 and Zero). To use Jazelle technology, you need an explicit agreement with ARM. No proper documentation exists publicly and free of cost.

This makes Jazelle quite useless for Raspbian Linux users. Furthermore, it is doubtful if modern Java JIT VMs don't already outpeform Jazelle on their own.

I suggest you forget about Jazelle and just use the official Oracle JVM included in official Raspbian images. It is pretty fast.

Comment: Maybe enlightening: https://stackoverflow.com/a/742918/1151724 And that's an anecdote from at least 10 years ago.

Comment: @goldilocks note that "the user" in that story is the implementer of a JVM. If you already have a JVM with Jazelle support, then there is no additional work.